# backup by compress tar each directory

Tags: backup, delete, tar

I’m looking for a method to scan a directory (not recursive) and tar it using the original folder name, and then delete the folder (so I will have only the folder compressed)
Anyone has the command for that?

Comment: What if the directory contains sub-directories?

Comment: Could you rephrase your question? It's not clear whether you want to tar a directory and then remove it, or tar subdirectories and then remove those subdirectories. In the latter case, what about files in the directories?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can suggest the following one-liner (supposing the current directory is the parent of the directories to backup):

```
for f in */; do tar -czf "${f%/}.tar.gz" "$f"; rm -rf "$f"; done
```

To change each folder name to lowercase, and substitute spaces with underscore:

```
for f in */; do f="${f// /_}"; f="${f,,}"; tar -czf "${f%/}.tar.gz" "$f" && rm -rf "$f"; done_
```

Comment: `find` combined with the `-maxdepth 1` option also takes hidden directories; `shopt -s dotglob` will do that too for this `for`

Comment: thanks! was helpful, is there a way to convert the names to "safe name" (i.e My Folder = my_folder) delete the spaces and make lowercase each tar?

Comment: I edited my answer for this your new request. By the way, you should remove this answer (that is not really an answer) and post it as a comment to my answer.